# What do you need to do to get Excel to read the styles in files created by the OpenXML SDK library?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

There seem to be a lot of problems with this library - often it seems to do the wrong thing despite you having written the data correctly - are there any 'magic' undocumented things you just need to know to get it to work or is it just full of bugs?!

I've come across some which Im going to post as an answer but any more 'gotchas' other people have found would be useful

Answer (score 0):

The things I have discovered so far are:

- You need to add a blank CellFormat if using custom elements in CellsFormats
- You need to add 2 blank Fills if using custom Fills
- You need to a 1 blank Border to the Borders element (if using)

If you dont do the above then excel just ignores the style elements you write into these locations.  This can be very confusing as the xml produced will look correct and you will see you eg Border configured correctly and applied correctly but when you open it in excel it wont do anything!